# How to set up rating stars and get its value on ionic V2?

Tags: ionic2

Are there any plugins or tips to make a rating stars on ionic V 2 ? I am new with it. I have tried to change dynamically the icon, but my problem is that I want to get the value of rating stars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [ionic2-rating](https://github.com/andrucz/ionic2-rating) or  [Creating a Rating Directive in Angular 2](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/10/creating-a-rating-directive-in-angular-2/).

Answer (score 0):

ionic2-rating is awesome but when I used it i was still unsure of how to actually allow a user to click on a star and affect the value (maybe I'm just a noob but the docs didnt make it clear)

So for anyone who stumbles on this here is how:

the docs say on **HTML side** to include

```
    (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"
```

but then what do you do on the .ts side to use data from this event firing? 
well you could change the method named 'onModelChange' to whatever you want, create that method on the .ts side accepting $event as a parameter, then set your rating to event.value, just like this:

on **.ts Side**:

```
   changeRating(event)
   {
      this.rating=event.value;
   }
```

Comment: this is an extension and elaboration onto the answer any bypasses nothing. I feel this is legitimately helpful to anyone who may need to use ionic2-rating but if my input and assistance in a Community forum is not welcome then ill simply refrain from partaking.