# Ionic2 rating bar issue

Tags: angular, ionic2, rating

I'm learning ionic2. I want to use rating stars in my app. I referred from this link [rating star ionic2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839086/how-to-set-up-rating-stars-and-get-its-value-on-ionic-v2). But I'm facing an issue in link this when I add the  tag [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxJvG.png).
Can anyone help me regarding it?

**rating.html**

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
<rating [(ngModel)]="rate" 
    readOnly="false"
    max="5"
    emptyStarIconName="star-outline" 
    halfStarIconName="star-half" 
    starIconName="star" 
    nullable="false"
    (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"></rating>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import **`Ionic2RatingModule`** inside the **`module.ts`**

```
import { Ionic2RatingModule } from 'ionic2-rating';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [

    ],
    imports: [
        Ionic2RatingModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [

    ]
})
```

Comment: Yes, I've imported the module. then also I'm getting the issue

Comment: Also you need to add under directives @Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/search/search.html',
  providers: [EmployeeService, UtilityService],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  directives: [Rating]
})